# Seeking advice for Item system in RPG game (Java)

Tags: java

everyone! So i've been doing some game ideas in my free time and i'm currently creating rpg item system. Firstly, i've made base class **Item**. It implements **Comparable** and i set its natural ordering by in-game name.

```
public abstract class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
    
    protected String inGameName;
    protected String description;
    protected int id;
    protected int value;
    
    public Item(int id, String inGameName, String description, int value) {
        this.id = id;
        this.inGameName = inGameName;
        this.description = description;
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    public String getInGameName() {
        return this.inGameName;
    }
    
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }
    
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }
    
    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Item))
            return false;
        else {
            Item otherItem = (Item) obj;
            Integer thisId = this.getId();
            Integer otherId = otherItem.getId();
            return thisId.equals(otherId);
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Item otherItem) {
        return this.inGameName.compareTo(otherItem.getInGameName());
    }
}
```

Afterwards, i created class **StackableItem** which implements **Stackable** interface. This class represents items that are stackable inside inventory such as materials, potions etc.

```
public interface Stackable {
    
    public int getStackLimit();
    public int getStackSize();
    public void setStackSize(int size);
    
}

public abstract class StackableItem extends Item implements Stackable {
    
    private int stackLimit;
    private int stackSize;
    
    public StackableItem(int id, String inGameName, String description, int value, int stackLimit, int stackSize) {
        super(id, inGameName, description, value);
        this.stackLimit = stackLimit;
        this.stackSize = stackSize;
    }
    
    public int getStackLimit() {
        return this.stackLimit;
    }
    
    public int getStackSize() {
        return this.stackSize;
    }
    
    public void setStackSize(int size) {
        this.stackSize = size;
    }
    
}
```

Finally, i've created **ConsumableItem** class that implements **Consumable** interface.

```
public interface Consumable {
    
    public boolean isItemOnCooldown();
    public int getCooldownTime();
    
}


public class ConsumableItem extends StackableItem implements Consumable {
    
    private boolean onCooldown;
    private int cooldownTime;
    
    public ConsumableItem(int id, String inGameName, String description, int value, int stackLimit, int stackSize, int cooldownTime) {
        super(id, inGameName, description, value, stackLimit, stackSize);
        this.cooldownTime = cooldownTime;
        this.onCooldown = false;
    }
    
    public boolean isItemOnCooldown() {
        return this.onCooldown;
    }
    
    public int getCooldownTime() {
        return this.cooldownTime;
    }
}
```

Obviously, there are missing functionalities such as effects on consuming, but these are first ideas. So now that i have ConsumableItem class, should i create subclasses for each item i want to create, for example Small Health Potion, Large Health Potion, Magic Scroll etc. or is it better to create Enum with predefined values for each item and use that info for instantiating ConsumableItem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a reminder that this is a space for asking questions like "why doesn't this work", whereas this is something that should go in a discussion forum (which the rules explicitly say SO is not). Just for the future :)

That being said, I would go enum because as a fellow game designer you never really know how many items you're going to compulsively add, and having a subclass for each one is gonna get tiring.